# Is there anyway to get the position of android menubar item?

Tags: android, android-activity, window, android-actionbar

I need to load Android dialog activity window once clicked on the icon in the action bar as displayed in the following image:
[image]

I know how to load the window using the following code.

```
resolver=getContentResolver();
layoutParams=getWindow().getAttributes();

layoutParams.x=400;
layoutParams.height=600;
layoutParams.width=1000;
layoutParams.y= 30;
this.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

What I need to know is if there is any way to find out the position of the icon in action bar, without using any code.

Comment: is that icon is menu icon? I mean is added through menu item with icon?

Comment: @IBunny if you have id of that menu item, then you can use `findViewById()` to get that menu item `View`...

Comment: @GopalRao Yes I can get the View of it. But what I want to do is once I clicked that icon I need to open dialog activity window. For that I need to get the position of the button.

Comment: Do you want to show PopupWindow at that Button location? by the way, you can get position of Menu Button in Window using `view.getLocalVisibleRect(Rect)`...

Comment: @GopalRao Not pop window. I need to start an another activity as a dialog window after clicked. Do you have any example about this method? I checked the documentation, but it does not has any description about the method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47206/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-ibunny)

Comment: You can get x and y position of that Menu Button... `int[] location = new int[2];
  view.getLocationInWindow(location);
  int xPosition = location[0];
  int yPosition = location[1];`...

Comment: @GopalRao It is not applicable for my case. I have few activities and this icon is in the menu bar(menu icon). So when  I call it using findViewById(), I'm getting Runtime Exception. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: where are you calling `findViewById()`? inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: @GopalRao Yes, inside onCreate() in dialog activity.

Comment: @IBunny Might be you have to provide more information. You said you are calling this in `onCreate()` in Dialog Activity. so are you overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in DialogActivity and inflating menu options? if that Menu is a part of DialogActivity, call `findViewById()` in `onWindowFocusChanged()` method.

Comment: I guess what most suspicious is it throws RuntimeException, which is not something supposed to be thrown even if the given ID wasn't there in the child path. It looks more like some other exception is wrapped by in the stack trace.

Comment: @GopalRao In my main activity I have override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method. Dialog Activity is separate activity which I want to open once I clicked on the  icon in action bar. I can set the position by the code as I given in the code but once the device changed the orientation, the window opens far away from the icon.  For that reason I need to find out the position of the icon.

Comment: @IBunny but you can get that position in `MainActivity` only... You can not get it in `DialogActivity` as that icon is not part of it...