# How can I get the x, y position of a ToolBarItem?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to notify the user if they need to set up a card. I have an animated ellipse that grows and shrinks (using [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Basics/PulsatingEllipsePage.xaml.cs)) to grab the user's attention, but I need help positioning it. I want it to be centered on the button that needs to be tapped.

If my XAML looks like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Card" Clicked="EditCard_Clicked" x:Name="CardButton"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

How can I get the on screen position of `CardButton`?

Comment: It is unavailable to get it in forms . You could use Custom Renderer and return the value in the renderer . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670760/is-there-anyway-to-get-the-position-of-android-menubar-item.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use NavigationPage?

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
   <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="title">
      <Button x:Name="thisButton" />
   </AbsoluteLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

```
title.add(eclipse, thisButton.X, thisButtonY);
```